# Can't get the correct index of a clicked slide

Tags: javascript

I'm writing this function for a slider, when I click on a slide I want to get its index.

When I log `clickedSlide` it outputs the correct slide, but for some reason `clickedSlideIndex` only returns odd index numbers (1, 3, 5, etc.)

```js
slides.forEach(slide => slide.onclick = handleSlideClick);

function handleSlideClick() {
    let clickedSlide = event.target;
    let clickedSlideIndex = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(clickedSlide.parentNode.childNodes, clickedSlide);

    // some stuff..
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't this: `slides.forEach(slide => slide.onclick = handleSlideClick)` - use event **delegation**

Comment: `childNodes` includes `textNodes`. Use `children`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The odd index numbers can be explained by the following example:

```js
document.getElementById('slides').onclick=handleSlideClick;

function handleSlideClick() {
  let clickedSlide = event.target;
  let clickedSlideIndex= Array.prototype.indexOf.call(clickedSlide.parentNode.childNodes, clickedSlide);
  console.log(clickedSlide,clickedSlideIndex);
}
```

```css
.slide {display:inline-block}
```

```html
<div id="slides">
 <div class="slide">one</div>&nbsp;
 <div class="slide">two</div>&nbsp;
 <div class="slide">three</div>&nbsp;
 <div class="slide">four</div>&nbsp;
 <div class="slide">five</div>&nbsp;
 <div class="slide">six</div>&nbsp;
</div>
```

Here each `div.slide` is followed by an `&nbsp;` (a "non-break-space") node. In the index-count this little entity counts too! If you want to avoid this from happening you could replace `.childNodes` with `.children`:

```js
document.getElementById('slides').onclick=handleSlideClick;

function handleSlideClick() {
  let clickedSlide = event.target;
  let clickedSlideIndex= Array.prototype.indexOf.call(clickedSlide.parentNode.children, clickedSlide);
  console.log(clickedSlide,clickedSlideIndex);
}
```

```css
.slide {display:inline-block}
```

```html
<div id="slides">
 <div class="slide">one</div>&nbsp;
 <div class="slide">two</div>&nbsp;
 <div class="slide">three</div>&nbsp;
 <div class="slide">four</div>&nbsp;
 <div class="slide">five</div>&nbsp;
 <div class="slide">six</div>&nbsp;
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
slides.forEach((slide, index) => {
   slide.onclick = () => handleSlideClick(index)
});

function handleSlideClick(index) {
    
   console.log(index) // prints the index

    // some stuff..
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I guess this will also work, but I'll stick to the cars10m's answer.